# Can I replace this broken potentiometer with resistors?

Tags: led, resistors, potentiometer, converter

I have a 100-watt DC DC boost converter 10-32V To 12-97V [like this one](https://www.aideepen.com/products/100w-120w-150w-dc-dc-boost-converter-step-up-power-supply-module-10-32v-to-12-97v-laptop-voltage-charge-board-for-arduino-on-aliexpress).

The micro potentiometer broke.  I'd like to wire in resistors (since I have some.)  I think I can do this because the output requirements are constant.

I have a 100-watt LED bulb that requires 3000mA and 30-34v.  My power source is a 11.1V 3-cell battery.

What resistor(s) should I solder in to replace the potentiometer?

[image: Boost Converter]

Comment: you are asking about component values on an unknown device... measure the potentiometer ... use resistors that match

Comment: Yes. You need to know the total resistance of potentiometer and the current wiper setting to know which resistors to use as replacement. Or at least know how the resistance values convert to whatever output voltage you want.

Comment: Measure the pot, if that's not possible, read the marking on it and look it up, see how the dial is set, and do some rough estimates to get the value, connect the resistor(s). Then get brave, remove the smoke alarm and power it on.

Comment: Haha.  Smoke alarms deactivated... check.

So, it says "W103 13."  What's that mean?

Comment: @NewGuyKnowsNothing the 103 means 10 kΩ (first two digits = 10, followed by third digit 3 zeroes, 10000 Ω or 10 kΩ). The W, at a wild guess, might mean it's dimensionally equivalent to the (very popular) Bourns 3296W series? It looks to be the same size and pin/screw layout. No clue about the 13. Could be a date code, lot code, or any number of things.

Comment: note that this is a very common potentiometer that you can find in any electronic components store or online. It should be very easy to order another potentiometer and solder it to replace the broken one. Resistors have discrete values, so if you want to fine tune the resistance value a potentiometer is a better option than using discrete resistors, specially this type of multiturn resistors where you can get good accuracy on the resistance value.

Answer (score 6):

If the module you have is the same as in the link you provided then the contol is being used as a rheostat, not as a potentiometer. This means that it is connected so that only one end and the wiper are used (the other end is connected to the wiper). You'll be able to tell which it is by looking at the bottom of the board, if two of the pins are connected together, it's being used as a rheostat. In this case you don't need two resistors, you only need one and it's value will be somewhere between 0\$\Omega\$ and the value marked on the pot, 10K. You'll still have to determine the needed value experimentally or by measuring the existing pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6jEZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Good catch.  I assume you figured it out from the upside down board image?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes.

Answer (score 4):

It's a 10kΩ pot, very common part.

You can replace it with two resistors that add up to 10kΩ (approximately).

The easiest way to figure out the required resistors is to wire a 10kΩ pot in place, adjust to get the desired output, then remove it and measure from wiper to each end.

Or you might just want to leave the pot in there if it's working okay.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two resistors that add up to the resistance marked on the potentiometer, more or less.  The exact resistance won't be critical.

But there's no way for us to know exactly what those resistors need to be, if all you have is a broken pot.  So you will have to do it by trial-and-error.  I would start with two resistors each half the pot's resistance.  If that's not right, adjust one up and one down, until you get the voltage you want.  Then solder them in place.